# How can I upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04LTS in one step with no downloads?

Tags: 12.04, 11.04, upgrade

I cannot use the Internet to update. How can I update my OS without using the update manager or the Internet?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can not.

Comment: what @mikewhatever is saying is that there's no straight upgrade path from 11.04 to 12.04 since 11.04 is not a LTS version. You would have to first upgrade to 11.10 and then to 12.04. LTS versions can only be upgraded from LTS to LTS or from one version back to LTS.

Comment: @james That's not at all what I said. :~) The OP wants to upgrade without downloading, which isn't possible, to begin with, and makes various ways and methods irrelevant.

Comment: @james Please read the title again. You can not upgrade from 11.04 to 12.04 in one step. If you know of such a way, please post your own answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the only way to upgrade your OS from 11.04 to 12.04LTS in one step, without any downloads, is to buy a new computer with 12.04LTS installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase a Disc from here http://www.osdisc.com/cgi-bin/view.cgi/products/linux/ubuntu and install it. There are other places to get such media so you might want to google it.

Answer (score 0):

You can purchase 12.04 LTS CD from the Ubuntu store, [right here](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976). The only way to upgrade with the internet is to have the installation media mailed to you.